# Integration test with Junit5, spring and docker

Tags: docker, spring-test, junit5

I want to run a test with [junit5-docker](https://faustxvi.github.io/junit5-docker/) and Spring test @Sql annotation to unit test a postgresql native query (I can't use HSQL DB here).

My problem is that the scripts inserted with Spring @Sql annotation are executed before the docker container creation end.

I can't find an acceptable way to order those elements so that the @Sql is executed just after the container is available.

Of course we could use a Thread.sleep(...) in the DataSource creation, but that's not really what I want to do...

EDIT : 
Test example (Kotlin) :

```
@Docker(image = "postgres:9.6", ports = [Port(exposed = 5433, inner = 5432)],

    environments = [
        Environment(key = "POSTGRES_DB", value = "nv2test"),
        Environment(key = "POSTGRES_USER", value = "postgres"),
        Environment(key = "POSTGRES_PASSWORD", value = "postgres")],

    waitFor = WaitFor("LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections"),
    newForEachCase = false)
@Sql(scripts = ["/data/clear.sql", "/data/operations.sql"])
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@TestExecutionListeners(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener::class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [DockerContainerConfig::class])
class OperationSearchRepositoryImplTest{
    @Test
    fun shouldFindByExample() {
         // Some test...
    }
}
```

The DockerContainerConfig is a Spring config class that only defines a DataSource to the postgres.

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Do you use `waitFor` param for `@Docker` annotation? As in [example](https://faustxvi.github.io/junit5-docker/) `waitFor = @WaitFor("mysqld: ready for connections"))`

Comment: Yes I use waitFor : the test itself will wait that the container is ready, but the @Sql is still executed before the @ Docker !

Comment: You need think about `TestExecutionListener` ordering. May be you need to override on of them and change ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try that !

Comment: Please show us exactly how you are registering the Docker and Spring extensions for JUnit Jupiter.

Comment: Ok I've just post an edit to my message with some example !

Comment: What happens if you move the `@Sql` declaration from the class level to the `@Test` method level?

Comment: I just tried this way, but the problem is the same : the @Sql is executed before the container initialization...

Comment: The only thing I can do is to wait for the container creation end within the DataSource bean creation method. This is not really elegant but it works!